# The return type of the controller method is not correctly determined

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

My controller method returns type **List**, but for some reason thymeleaf.TemplateEngine is trying to find a template with the name "test3", not finding, gives the following:

> Exception processing template "test3": Error resolving template [test3], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Although the documentation says that:

> Any return value that does not match any of the earlier values in this table and that is a String or void is treated as a view name (default view name selection through RequestToViewNameTranslator applies), **provided it is not a simple type**, as determined by BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty...
>   [docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types)

```java
@Controller
public class MyControllerTest3 {
     @GetMapping(path = "/test3", produces = { "application/json" })
     public List<RecordTable3> f1 () { 
         List<RecordTable3> recInTable = new ArrayList<RecordTable3>();
         recInTable.add(new RecordTable3(1,"test1","test2","test3"));
         recInTable.add(new RecordTable3(2,"test4","test5","test6"));
         return recInTable;
     }
}
```

Comment: Use ResponseEntity to return value in your controller

Comment: Thanks !!! Everything works with ResponseEntity, but it is not clear why the above code does not work.

Comment: It was necessary to replace Controller with RestController